# Using form_for to create select tag with data being pulled from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to create a select tag to create a dropdown menu that will list down all items from the City database. I was able to do it but I had to hard code an HTML form tag.

```
<form>
    <%= select_tag :city, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, :id, :city_name), class: "form-control" %>
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to convert this code so that I could place it in the form_for tag, but I keep getting this error: "undefined method `city_id'" from the f.collection_select line.

```
<%= form_for @city do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :city_id, "City list" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id, :city_name %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried removing :city_id, but then I get a "wrong number of arguments (3 for 4..6)", I replaced :city_id with nil and I get the same undefined method error.

I new to rails so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form_for` helper wraps an object (in your case, this is `@city`) and then creates form fields to fill in its attributes, directly. So, based on your error message, it sounds like `@city` does not respond to `:city_id`. In other words, `@city.city_id` would give the same error. So you need to figure out what attribute you are intending to fill in here.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it. I don't have a "city_id" in my cities database, I just used "id" instead and it worked. It's such a simple problem but I don't know the ins and outs of Rails yet.